# Why is App crashing when loading a pre populated DB into Core Data upon first open on Older Devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, memory

With my App I have a pre-populated sqlite DB that I created using core data from another app I created so the Data model is the same. I copy it over and everything works great.  I tried it on every iOS device that can run iOS 6.0 because that is what I am building for.  Even on the early iPod Touches the App works.  It takes around 45 secs for the DB to copy over on the older devices.  The app works all the data is there and all devices the tests were great and no issues.  I released the app on the app store and found out that on the older devices the app is crashing when it first loads.  I am assuming that it is a memory related issue.  I am mostly confused that the customers that purchased it that I am in communication with have the same phone an iPhone 4S and one reports it works fine while the other says it crashes. I am thinking that one has a early 4S while the other has a later 4S.  I confirmed that they had room on the phone to copy the data also. When I run the app from Xcode it never crashes no matter the device.

My Question is does any one know why this is happening and a possible fix?

Maybe there is a more efficient way that doesn't make the app take almost a min to load for the first time?  Any help would be great because I am at a loss.  I looked at about 30 other questions that are some what like this one but they really don't answer the question I need.

I would also just like to say Thank You to all of You because I live on this site and have learned a lot from all your questions and Answers.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.sqlite"];

#define UPGRADE_COPY_STORE_FROM_BUNDLE

#ifdef UPGRADE_COPY_STORE_FROM_BUNDLE
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
        NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"sqlite" inDirectory:nil];
        NSError *anyError = nil;
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dataPath toPath:[storeURL path] error:&anyError];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"Error copying file: %@", anyError);
    }
#endif


    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Also attached is the Crash Log from a Device. Updated

```
    Incident Identifier: CCFB748D-5A2A-45CE-B9EC-19811CCDC696
CrashReporter Key:   71b2c2b3b88abfe03baa87e7f588642dcec0ff08
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         Upgrade [2513]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/27C440D4-0210-48BB-A287-570FAEDE3369/Upgrade.app/Upgrade
Identifier:      Upgrade
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-27 23:23:57.479 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.JonPhillips.Upgrade failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.450 (user 2.450, system 0.000), 12% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.528, 3% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39b84570 read + 8
1   libcopyfile.dylib               0x39a70df4 copyfile_internal + 4616
2   libcopyfile.dylib               0x39a72196 copyfile + 3326
3   Foundation                      0x32301cb4 -[NSFilesystemItemCopyOperation _handleFTSEntry:] + 384
4   Foundation                      0x323014a2 -[NSDirectoryTraversalOperation main] + 334
5   Foundation                      0x322af5bc -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836
6   Foundation                      0x322fdd1e -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:] + 238
7   Upgrade                         0x0009f438 -[JPPAppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] (JPPAppDelegate.m:186)
8   Upgrade                         0x0009ef30 -[JPPAppDelegate managedObjectContext] (JPPAppDelegate.m:150)
9   Upgrade                         0x0009f95e -[MainScreenViewController viewDidLoad] (MainScreenViewController.m:35)
10  UIKit                           0x33849590 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
11  UIKit                           0x338c3fb8 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 80
12  UIKit                           0x338c3f5e -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 26
13  UIKit                           0x3386e05c -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 292
14  UIKit                           0x3386e642 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 150
15  UIKit                           0x338c6ca2 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 130
16  UIKit                           0x3389130c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132
17  UIKit                           0x33849e10 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 504
18  UIKit                           0x3382c40e -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 326
19  UIKit                           0x3382c2be -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 26
20  UIKit                           0x33889e46 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 270
21  UIKit                           0x33885ae8 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 360
22  UIKit                           0x338c71e4 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
23  Upgrade                         0x0009e896 -[JPPAppDelegate initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize] (JPPAppDelegate.m:64)
24  Upgrade                         0x0009e106 -[JPPAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (JPPAppDelegate.m:22)
25  UIKit                           0x3388aad4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
26  UIKit                           0x3388a65e -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1186
27  UIKit                           0x33882846 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
28  UIKit                           0x3382ac34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
29  UIKit                           0x3382a6c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
30  UIKit                           0x3382a116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
31  GraphicsServices                0x3551a5a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
32  GraphicsServices                0x3551a1ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
33  CoreFoundation                  0x319f7170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
34  CoreFoundation                  0x319f7112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
35  CoreFoundation                  0x319f5f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
36  CoreFoundation                  0x31968eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
37  CoreFoundation                  0x31968d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
38  UIKit                           0x33881480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
39  UIKit                           0x3387e2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
40  Upgrade                         0x0009e0b8 main (main.m:16)
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x39accb1c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39b83648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39abc4ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39aaedf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39b82eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39b83048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x319f7040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x319f5d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31968eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31968d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3794c500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39aec30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39aec1d4 thread_start + 4

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: Attach a crash report!

Comment: I checked in itunes connect and viewed the crash logs and it says there are none.  How ever the reviews and people who have emailed me say different.

Comment: @Kerni is the edited crash log helpful to see what caused the crash?

Comment: Now you need to symbolicate it. There is plenty of documentation around how to do that.

Comment: @Kerni Thanks for taking the time to look at this Kerni.  I believe i symbolicated it correctly.  Does this look better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are copying the data on the main thread, which blocks it far too long. It should never ever be blocked for 1 second or longer. Otherwise the iOS watchdog will kill your process.

The specific crash report shows the app was killed, because it took too long to start up: `com.JonPhillips.Upgrade failed to launch in time`.

The copy action is even running from inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. The watchdog timer is even shorter for having this method end! Check the WWDC sessions for exact timing if you are interested in them. I don't recall in which specifically it was mentioned.

If you require such tasks, move them to a background thread. If this tasks means that the user cannot do anything in the app, show a specific UI telling the user what is going on and giving some indication how long it will take, e.g. a progress bar, and/or some text "Step 1 of 3: Copying data".

Comment: I understand moving the method to a background thread. Thanks for that help.  I assume I would call that method on the first view controller and handle it like you said with a notice of what is happening? Is this correct?

Comment: That's totally up to you how to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to just have the app use the database in the bundle and avoid copying it to the device?

Comment: Please open a new question for this and provide the required information so people are able to answer that question. It has nothing to do with the described problem.